# Do accepted answers turn green only on MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, design, accepted-answer, mathoverflow

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284230/what-does-it-mean-to-suspect-that-two-conjectures-are-logically-equivalent), the accepted answer has a green background, I don't think I've ever seen that before on any Stack Exchange website, does it happen only on MathOverflow?

Comment: Somebody made a [userscript](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1573) to change this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. MathOverflow has a rather unique design, which resembles the early design of Stack Overflow as e.g. in [this famous picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: Yeah this is something they did on their own while it was still a 1.0 site and they kept their design when they rejoined the network. It's hideous and makes the text hard to read but nothing we can do about it because I think it might have been part of their agreement that we can't redesign their site or something.

Comment: @animuson How is that possible? Was it an independent website that joined SE? Do they have their own dev team and access to SE servers? Do they regularly hold referendums to decide what to do? :) Why they had all these privileges to begin with? Why they're so special? Many other sites are far more popular on SE. The dupe question says they're independent but they don't say why and how. Could they use another Q&A software? Do SE get money from ads there. I need to open another question. I only wanted to know about the green, now I have a billion question